# MultiLayerPerceptron - arbitrary way to detect superfluous inputs

Tags: java, neural-network, neuroph

I am using a `MultiLayerPerceptron` network (of the Neuroph API). It has 65 inputs. The network is **properly trained and does what it should do.**

However probably the neural network could do the same with only half of the inputs. I am looking for **an aribitrary way to detect which inputs are superfluous (i.e. the lowest impact on the output) ?**

At first I thought I could just loop through the weights. However, then I realized that there are actually a bunch of factors that I overlooked. It probably depends on the function, and also there are actually multiple weights for a single input, and I don't know how to connect the dots.

Nevertheless it would be a really valuable feature. So, I started to wonder **is this feature available in the API somewhere ?**